# How do I save a callable in a django model?

Tags: django, django-models, callable

I have a Django model which I need to hold a callable (in this case a reference to another model) to store it along with some "conditions" which should later be applied to the model.

My approach was like so:

```
MODEL_CHOICES = (
     (django.contrib.auth.models.User, 'User'),
     [some more]
     )
class Model:
     chosen_model = models.IntegerField(choices=MODEL_CHOICES)
     conditions = models.TextField()
```

Conditions would look something like this:

```
{'status': 1, [some other]}
```

But obviously

```
django.contrib.auth.models.User
```

is not a valid integer.

What I try to achive is the following:
Call

```
chosen_model.objects.filter(**conditions)
```

in a view.
Is this even possible? If yes, what kind of Field do I need to store a reference to a model?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use the [ContentType](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#the-contenttype-model) model here.

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class YourModel:
     chosen_model = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
     conditions = models.TextField()
```

Comment: +1 Perfect answer, I wasn't aware of ContentType, seems pretty useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

looks like you may want a foreign key to [content type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/)